# Invariance subspace of linear operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Consider two commutative linear operators $A$ and $B$ and subspace $U$ , which invariance in $A$. Is it true that $U$ invariance in $B$?

I thought about root-subspace $V^{\lambda} = Ker(A- \lambda E)$ and about decomposition of $U$ into root-subspaces. And after that it's easy to see , that one root-subspace of $A$ invariance in $B$. And maybe we could get some induction.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Take $A = I$ to be the identity operator and $B$ to be any operator such that $B \neq cI$ (for some $c \in \mathbb{F}$). Then any subspace $U$ is $A$-invariant but not any subspace is $B$-invariant.

For example, we can take $B$ to be the operator acting on $\mathbb{F}^2$ as the matrix

$$ B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Then $U := \operatorname{span} \{ e_1 + e_2 \}$ is not $B$-invariant but it is $A$-invariant.

Comment: $I$ - unity operator?

Comment: @openspace: Yep.

Comment: It is usually called the identity operator... Indeed, this does not hold in general. Invariant subspaces of $A$ that are also invariant under any $B$ commuting with $A$ are called _hyperinvariant_.